# Count the number of events attended for a specific user in Cloudant using mapreduce

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, nosql, cloudant

I'm using Cloudant's `map reduce` functionality and I want to find how many events (count of events object)  the specific user with name (input from user) has attended for a date range (input from user).

I have docs that look like below.

```
{
 user: {
  name: 'peter pan'
 },
 startEventDateTime: <timestamp>,
 endDateDateTime: <timestamp>,
 events: [
  {
    name: 'La la land',
    text: 'more info'
  },
  {
    name: 'La la land',
    text: 'more info'
  }
 ]
}
```

Above means, user attended 2 events between between that start and end time. There are many documents for the same user for a different date range too with the events attended list.

How can I achieve this in Cloudant map reduce?

My Attempt:
unable to get map correctly. I can filter by name by doing 
map:

```
function (doc) {
  emit([doc.user, doc.events, startEventDateTime, endDateDateTime], doc)
}
```

reduce:

```
function (keys, values, rereduce) {
  if (rereduce) {
    return sum(values);
  } else {
    return values.length;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest considering a different format for your documents. Instead of having a user document with a list of events, make a separate document for each event, timestamped for the time at which it happened, such as:

```
{
  "_id": "c48ee0881ce7c5d39243d2243d2e63cb",
  "_rev": "1-c2f71fba5f09b129f1db20785f2429b2",
  "user": "bob",
  "datetime": "Thu 30 Nov 2017 09:46:02 GMT",
  "event": {
    "name": "lalaland",
    "text": "more info"
  }
}
```

Then you can rely on MapReduce to pick out date ranges per user. Here's a map function that does just that:

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc && doc.user && doc.datetime) {
    var when = new Date(Date.parse(doc.datetime));
    emit([doc.user, when.getFullYear(), when.getMonth(), when.getDay()], 1);
  }
}
```

and using the built-in reduce `_sum`. You can now use key ranges to slice the data. Say you want the events attended by user `bob` in Aug, 2017:

```
curl 'https://ACCT.cloudant.com/DBNAME/_design/DDOC/_view/VIEWNAME?startkey=\["bob", 2017, 7\]&endkey=\["bob", 2017, 8]&group=true&inclusive_end=false&reduce=true'

{
  "rows": [
    {
      "key": [
        "bob",
        2017,
        7,
        4
      ],
      "value": 1
    }
  ]
}
```